# How to optimize o(n**2) algorithm to become o(nlogn) or o(n)?

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to complete a hackerrank problem where you are given two arrays. One being a list of scores and another being a list of scores from a specific person. You have to determine the ranking of that person for each score. 
For example:

```
scores = [100,90,80]
alice = [80,90,100]
```

The output should be 3,2,1 because that is how alice would place if you were to compare it with the scores in the array scores. If you tie, then you take the same ranking.

I have tried using only one loop and using the range command but that completely failed and I am not getting remotely close answers. The working solution is a o(n**2) solution and it passes all the tests except the big ones, in which it times out.

```
def climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice):
    scores = list(set(scores))
    new_list = []
    alcount = 1
    for i in alice:
        for x in scores:
            if i < x:
                alcount += 1
        new_list.append(alcount)
        alcount = 1
    return new_list
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the dictionary on the fly within a list comprehension to achieve this in one line:

```
result = [ d[s] for d in [{a:i+1 for i,a in enumerate(scores)}] for s in alice ]
```

This will give you the answer in O(N+M) time where N is len(scores) and M is len(alice)

Answer (score 4):

Put the scores into a dict:

```
scores = {100:1, 90:2, 80:3}
```

Now it's a direct look-up for each of Alice's scores to convert to the desired output list.

Comment: What is O() of this solution?

Comment: @MatthewFisher The solution is **O(N+M)**: one linear pass (N) on the scores to build the dict, one linear pass on Alice's list (M) to produce the output list.

Comment: @Krish: Asking for the specific code to create that dict suggests that you should work through a tutorial on dictionaries.  SO is not a coding service, and this is one of many basic techniques you'll need to know as you progress in Python.  If you prefer, you can search for directly applicable code in previous answers on SO.